# dd: unrecognized operand when flashing kernel to partition during installation of arch linux

Tags: bash, arch-linux, partition, usb, dd

If this is the wrong place to ask, please tell me where to ask. I am currently following [this](https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv8/mediatek/acer-chromebook-r13) tutorial. I had issues with step 10, so I found a different mirror link to install. I am now on step 11. After typing

```
dd if=root/boot/vmlinux.kpart of/=/dev/sda1
```

I get this error: `dd: unrecognized operand ‘of/=/dev/sda1’`

I tried typing sudo in front of it, but that didn't do anything. I've tried implementing the information I found in the first four search results on stack but 1. I am honestly just following the tutorial and have no real experience using bash and 2. I don't think they apply but I could be wrong!

I looked up the documentation to see if my syntax was incorrect but as far as I can tell, its written correctly. Can someone please help me out and tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've been working on this all day and I'm working myself up.  Heres what I typed for step 10 if that matters...

```
localhost /tmp # mkdir root
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘root’: File exists
localhost /tmp # mount /dev/sda2 root
mount: /tmp/root: /dev/sda2 already mounted on /tmp/root.
localhost /tmp # tar -xf ArchLinuxARM-oak-latest.tar.gz -C root
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'LIBARCHIVE.xattr.security.capability'
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'LIBARCHIVE.xattr.security.capability'
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'LIBARCHIVE.xattr.security.capability' #according to a thread on here, this just comes from when i used my mac to flash it and doesn't affect anything
```

EDIT: Here is what is listed under my partitions

```
localhost /tmp # fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 7.3 GiB, 7875706880 bytes, 15382240 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 373.7 MiB, 391835648 bytes, 765304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 7.3 MiB, 7610368 bytes, 14864 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/loop6: 1.9 GiB, 2063953920 bytes, 4031160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


GPT PMBR size mismatch (61063167 != 61071359) will be corrected by write.
The backup GPT table is not on the end of the device. This problem will be corrected by write.
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 29.1 GiB, 31268536320 bytes, 61071360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D18EA7A7-761A-2E49-A17C-EE32240E7514

Device            Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1  8704000 61063119 52359120   25G Microsoft basic data
/dev/mmcblk0p2    20480    53247    32768   16M ChromeOS kernel
/dev/mmcblk0p3  4509696  8703999  4194304    2G ChromeOS root fs
/dev/mmcblk0p4    53248    86015    32768   16M ChromeOS kernel
/dev/mmcblk0p5   315392  4509695  4194304    2G ChromeOS root fs
/dev/mmcblk0p6    16448    16448        1  512B ChromeOS kernel
/dev/mmcblk0p7    16449    16449        1  512B ChromeOS root fs
/dev/mmcblk0p8    86016   118783    32768   16M Microsoft basic data
/dev/mmcblk0p9    16450    16450        1  512B ChromeOS reserved
/dev/mmcblk0p10   16451    16451        1  512B ChromeOS reserved
/dev/mmcblk0p11      64    16447    16384    8M unknown
/dev/mmcblk0p12  249856   315391    65536   32M EFI System

Partition table entries are not in disk order.

Disk /dev/mmcblk0boot1: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mmcblk0boot0: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/dm-0: 2 GiB, 2087714816 bytes, 509696 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/encstateful: 7.3 GiB, 7875706880 bytes, 15382240 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 7.5 GiB, 8006926336 bytes, 15638528 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 991D5A3D-42FB-7341-83B0-335B9F2F54BA
Device     Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1   8192    73727    65536   32M ChromeOS kernel
/dev/sda2  73728 15638494 15564767  7.4G Linux filesystem
```

Comment: it tells you that it does not like this operand `of/=/dev/sda1` ... what do you want to ask about it? ... there is no question in your post .... what documentation did you look at?

Answer (score 1):

The error message very much tells you what the problem is.

```
dd if=root/boot/vmlinux.kpart of=/dev/sda1
```